# Showing a map is surjective. It seems kind of tricky...

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I have a map which I want to show is surjective.   (It is only one small part of a much larger problem involving constructing a homeomorphism from the space $[([0,1]\times S^{n-1})/(\{1\}\times S^{n-1})]/(\{0\}\times S^{n-1})$.

If that notation is unfamiliar that's OK because it is irrelevant to my problem below:

I want to show that the map $g:[0,1]\times S^{n-1}\to S^n$ defined by $g(t,x) = \cos(\pi t)e_{n+1} + \sin(\pi t)x$ is surjective.

Here, $S^{n-1} = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n} : |x| = 1\}$ and $S^{n}$ is defined in the only consistent way.  Also, by $e_{n}$ I mean the $n$th standard basis vector for Euclidean space.

The beginning of my approach is this:

Let $y\in S^{n}$.  Then write $y = \Sigma_{i=1}^{n+1}y_{i}e_{i}$.  By linear independence, I know immediately that if I want $g(t,x) = y$, I need to have
$t = \cos^{-1}(y_{n+1})/\pi$ (chosen from $[0,\pi]$).

After typing this out I'm sort of having an idea, but since I've already typed the entire question out now I might as well post it.  I'll post back with any updates.  Thanks for any hints or suggestions you can give!

Update:  I got it.  Take $x = (y - y_{n+1}e_{n+1})$ and scale appropriately.

Sorry to trouble the crowd with this.  I guess I just needed to organize the thinking process to figure it out!

Comment: I was "upping" your comment/ replying to it but it disappeared.

The vector you pointed out, which is $y - y_{n+1}e_{n+1}$ needed to be scaled by a factor of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - y_{n+1}^2}}$ and then it worked out perfectly and still had norm $\leq 1$.

Comment: Wait...  it needs to be $= 1$.   Hmmm... back to the drawing board?

Comment: I decided to slightly expand it and make it an answer.

Comment: Er...  I think I can use Pythagoras to show that it is exactly norm $1$, since $y$ and $y-y_{n+1}e_{n+1}$ are orthogonal.

Edit:  note my error as pointed out below.

Comment: Do you mean $y_ne_{n+1}$ and $y-y_{n+1}e_{n+1}$ are othogonal?

Comment: Annother error:  a sign issue in my scaling factor.

Comment: The nice thing is that $\sin(\pi t)$ is always nonnegative for $t\in[0,1]$ so you don't really need to worry about its sign.  You just need the fact that if $z\in \mathbb R^n$ has norm $a\geq 0$, then $z=ax$ for some $x\in S^{n-1}$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2252/discussion-between-borninthe80s-and-jonas-meyer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by noting that $t\mapsto \cos(\pi t)$ maps $[0,1]$ onto $[-1,1]$, and therefore there exists $t\in[0,1]$ such that $y_{n+1}=\cos(\pi t)$.  Then you can use the Pythagorean identity for $\cos$ and $\sin$ to find the norm of $\sum_1^n y_ie_i$.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks!